# Checking if a type is a map

Tags: c++, dictionary, c++14, type-traits

I sometimes find the need to write general routines that can be applied to a  container of objects, or a map of such containers (i.e. process each container in the map). One approach is to write separate routines for map types, but I think it can be more natural and less verbose to have one routine that works for both types of input:

```
template <typename T>
auto foo(const T& items)
{ 
    return foo(items, /* tag dispatch to map or non-map */);
}
```

What is a safe, clean way to do this tag dispatch?

Comment: Check if it has nested `key_type` and `mapped_type` types?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The existing answers test for very specific properties of `std::map`, either that it is precisely a specialization of `std::map` (which would be false for `std::unordered_map` or non-standard types with the same interface as `std::map`), or testing that its `value_type` is exactly `std::pair<const key_type, mapped_type>` (which would be true for `multimap` and `unordered_map`, but false for non-standard types with similar interfaces).

This only tests that it provides `key_type` and `mapped_type` members, and can be accessed with `operator[]`, so doesn't say that `std::multimap` is mappish:

```
#include <type_traits>

namespace detail {
  // Needed for some older versions of GCC
  template<typename...>
    struct voider { using type = void; };

  // std::void_t will be part of C++17, but until then define it ourselves:
  template<typename... T>
    using void_t = typename voider<T...>::type;

  template<typename T, typename U = void>
    struct is_mappish_impl : std::false_type { };

  template<typename T>
    struct is_mappish_impl<T, void_t<typename T::key_type,
                                     typename T::mapped_type,
                                     decltype(std::declval<T&>()[std::declval<const typename T::key_type&>()])>>
    : std::true_type { };
}

template<typename T>
struct is_mappish : detail::is_mappish_impl<T>::type { };
```

Because `is_mappish` has a "base characteristic" of either `true_type` or `false_type` you can dispatch on it like so:

```
template <typename T>
auto foo(const T& items, true_type)
{
    // here be maps
}

template <typename T>
auto foo(const T& items, false_type)
{
    // map-free zone
}

template <typename T>
auto foo(const T& items)
{ 
    return foo(items, is_mappish<T>{});
}
```

Or you can avoid dispatching entirely, and just overload `foo` for maps and non-maps:

```
template <typename T,
          std::enable_if_t<is_mappish<T>{}, int> = 0>
auto foo(const T& items)
{
    // here be maps
}

template <typename T,
          std::enable_if_t<!is_mappish<T>{}, int> = 0>
auto foo(const T& items)
{
    // map-free zone
}
```

Comment: `is_mappish_impl` made me chuckle. :)

Comment: although, this solution is also only valid when the non standard map implements the interface of standard associative container, this is also may break.

Comment: @DavidHaim, yes obviously. If the type doesn't implement a specific interface then you probably don't want to dispatch to a template function that relies on that interface. The trait can easily be tailored to check whatever parts of the map interface are relevant to the OP's `foo` that works with maps, for whatever definition of "map" is relevant to the function.

Comment: Can this be used on a variable `var`, in such a way that (generically naming `is_map` to a function) `is_map(var)` returns a `bool`?

Comment: @sancho.sReinstateMonica yes of course, just write a function template that returns the value of the `is_mappish` trait for the function parameter type.

Answer (score 12):

This has worked for me, not tested 100% though:

```
template <class T>
struct isMap {
    static constexpr bool value = false;
};

template<class Key,class Value>
struct isMap<std::map<Key,Value>> {
    static constexpr bool value = true;
};

int main() {
    constexpr bool b1 = isMap<int>::value; //false
    constexpr bool b2 = isMap<std::vector<int>>::value; //false
    constexpr bool b3 = isMap<std::map<int,std::string>>::value; //true
    constexpr bool b4 = isMap<std::future<int>>::value; //false
}
```

Comment: Worth noting this only works for `std::map` and not the other 'map' types (e.g. `std::unordered_map`). I should have probably been more specific in the question.

Comment: @Daniel then add a specialization for unordered_map if thats needed

Comment: @Daniel I was assuming you talked about standard regular map. this can be easily be converted to support std::unordered_map , and subsequently isAnyMap. even though , I doubt that someone will use more then 1-2 types of maps in the same project..

Comment: I think this will break for maps with custom allocators and comparators. It can easily be fixed by adding two more template parameters.

Comment: Can this be used on a variable `var`, in such a way that (generically naming `is_map` to a function) `is_map(var)` returns a `bool`?

Comment: This also doesn't work for `const std::map`, `std::map&`, etc. You can use `std::decay` before feeding it into `isMap`.

Answer (score 3):

Here's what I came up with:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

namespace detail
{
    template <typename T, typename = void>
    struct IsMap : std::false_type {};

    template <typename T>
    struct IsMap<T, std::enable_if_t<
                        std::is_same<typename T::value_type,
                                    std::pair<const typename T::key_type,
                                              typename T::mapped_type>
                        >::value>
    > : std::true_type {};
}

template <typename T>
constexpr bool is_map = detail::IsMap<T>::value;

namespace { template <bool> struct MapTagImpl {}; }
using MapTag    = MapTagImpl<true>;
using NonMapTag = MapTagImpl<false>;

template <typename T>
using MapTagType = MapTagImpl<is_map<T>>;
```

Comment: Deriving from `true_type` or `false_type` is simpler than defining `static constexpr bool value`. Also your trait is true for multimaps, which might not be desirable (they don't have the same interface).

Comment: Can this be used on a variable `var`, in such a way that (generically naming `is_map` to a function) `is_map(var)` returns a `bool`?