# Detect if type is a "mapping"

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming

I'd like to parse c++ containers into another object using their `::iterator` member type. Containers who's iterator member type points to an object of a single type (vectors, queues, etc.) will turn into a list-like object, and containers who's iterator member type points to an `std::pair` will turn into a map-like object.

I'm trying to write a member function to detect the latter kind of container, but it does not work. Here's what I have so far:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <iterator>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
struct is_pair : std::false_type { };

template <typename T, typename U>
struct is_pair<std::pair<T, U>> : std::true_type { };

template <typename T>
constexpr bool is_pair_v = is_pair<T>::value;

template <typename...>
struct is_mapping : std::false_type { };

template <typename Container>
struct is_mapping<Container, std::enable_if_t<
    is_pair_v<std::iterator_traits<typename Container::iterator>::value_type>
>> : std::true_type { };

template <typename T>
constexpr bool is_mapping_v = is_mapping<T>::value;

#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << "is_pair:" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Map:    " << is_pair_v<std::iterator_traits<std::map<int, int>::iterator>::value_type> << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Vector: " << is_pair_v<std::iterator_traits<std::vector<int>::iterator>::value_type>   << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::cout << "is_mapping:" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Map:    " << is_mapping_v<std::map<int, int>> << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Vector: " << is_mapping_v<std::vector<int>>   << std::endl;
}
```

For some reason, `is_mapping_v` is always false and the code results in this output:

```
$ g++ -std=c++14 temp.cc && ./a.out
is_pair:
Map:    1
Vector: 0

is_mapping:    
Map:    0
Vector: 0
```

What is wrong with my code?

---

**Note:** This is not the a duplicate of [Checking if a type is a map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35293470/checking-if-a-type-is-a-map). The answer to that question uses the `::key_type` and `::mapped_type` members to detect the map (It fails for classes such as `std::multimap`). I am also explicitly using the fact that the iterator points to `std::pair`s later in my code, so checking that makes a lot more sense.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Checking if a type is a map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35293470/checking-if-a-type-is-a-map)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
is_pair_v<std::iterator_traits<typename Container::iterator>::value_type>
```

should be

```
is_pair_v<typename std::iterator_traits<typename Container::iterator>::value_type>
```

because `value_type` is a type. Without the `typename`, it will be parsed as a value and fail the `enable_if`, thus falling back to the primary template.

The reason your tests in `main` yield the correct value is because the templates there have already been instantiated and there is no ambiguity whether `value_type` is a type or value.

The second error is your primary template

```
template<typename...>
```

should be

```
template<typename, typename = void>
```

Otherwise, `is_mapping<T>` will never be the specialization with two arguments because the argument count mismatch.

[Live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b89c6a32ae250c48)

Comment: Even with that fix, this still doesn't work: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2ab49251e70c35aa

Comment: @Justin You're right, forgot to mention I fixed the primary template, oops

Answer (score 4):

The compiler is not selecting the partially specialized struct. There are two reasons for this:

1. You do an `enable_if` off of `is_pair_v<std::iterator_traits<typename Container::iterator>::value_type>`. The compiler would see `std::iterator_traits<...>::value_type` as a value instead of a type, but SFINAE kicks in and this is just silently removed.
2. Using `template <typename...>` makes it so that the specialization isn't selected. If I am right, this is because `is_mapping<T>` could either resolve to `is_mapping<T>` using the initial definition, or `is_mapping<T, void>` using the specialization. It seems that `is_mapping<T>` is preferred in this case.

   Fixing this is as easy as changing that to `template <typename, typename = void>`:

```
template <typename, typename = void>
struct is_mapping : std::false_type { };

template <typename Container>
struct is_mapping<Container, std::enable_if_t<
    is_pair_v<typename std::iterator_traits<typename Container::iterator>::value_type>
>> : std::true_type { };
```

---

However, a simpler implementation of `is_mapping` would be:

```
template <typename Container>
struct is_mapping : is_pair<
    typename std::iterator_traits<typename Container::iterator>::value_type
> {};
```

Basically, your version looks like

```
if (is_pair(...)) return true;
else return false;
```

Whereas you could simply do

```
return is_pair(...)
```

Comment: The simpler implementation does not work for types which do not have an `::iterator` member type.