# C++ map with custom value_type

Tags: c++, dictionary

For a `std::map<K, V>` the default `value_type` is `std::pair<const K, V>`. Is there a way to use a custom `value_type`? As far as I can tell you can't.

Edit: To be clear, a custom `value_type` might be something like this:

```
struct Edge {
  K from;
  V to;

  int calculate_thing();
  void print_debug();
};
```

E.g. suppose I have some existing function that I don't want to change like this:

```
template<typename It>
void processEdges(It begin, It end) {
   for(auto it = begin; it != end; ++it) {
     do_stuff(it->from);
     do_more_stuff(it->calculate_thing());
  }
}
```

Comment: Why would you even want to customize that? Drop the `const` on the key type? Then you'd violate the type invariants. I can't think of a use case here...?

Comment: What's your usecase here?

Comment: what do you mean with "custom value type" exactly? You choose `K` you choose `V`, what else would you customize?

Comment: There are other containers with other `value_type`s. Find whatever container you're looking for, or create one yourself.

Comment: imho the first part of your example helps a lot to understand the question, but not the second. Because for the funtion you could simply use a different container (eg `std::vector`), not clear why it has to be a map in this case

Comment: It has to be a `map` so I can look `Edge`'s up by key. I mean, that's the whole point of a `map`. How much motivation do you guys need?

Comment: It would be a whole lot easier to have `calculate_thing(*it)`. The problem here is the desire to add methods to each node, when free functions would be easier. Sure, free functions can't access private members, but `std::pair` does not have any private members anyway.

Comment: @Timmmm  I really think you could use a `set` here, with a custom comparator that only compares the key part of your `Edge` struct. The difference between a `set` and a `map` (for this use case) is only that in a `map` the key is separate while in a `set` the key and the value are in the same type/object/structure.

Comment: @Rene: That is not the only difference, e.g. to update a value you have to remove it and then reinsert it. It's also a bit icky because `set<T>` assumes that `!(a < b) && !(b < a)` means that `a == b` which I would be violating. It's definitely a valid option though.

Comment: @MSalters: I think you missed "some existing function **that I don't want to change**".

Comment: "How much motivation do you guys need?" as I wrote, the first part of the example is already motivation enough for me. Too often I have the key already stored with the value and feel bad for storing the key twice just to be able to use `std::map` for convenience

Comment: `struct Edge` - if you're looking at graphs, you might want Boost::Graph.

Answer (score 7):

It's always `std::pair<const K, V>`, you can't change that.

If you need a custom `value_type`, maybe you could use `std::set` (preferably with a [transparent comaprator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20317413/what-are-transparent-comparators)).

Comment: Yeah `std::set` is an option, but it's not quite the same - for instance if you want to change a value you have to remove it and then insert it again. Also the interface is not quite as nice.

Comment: @Timmmm This is also true for a map when you want to change the key! For both maps and sets you can only change the value.

Comment: @Timmmm Even though you have to remove it, you can minimzie the cost of it by using insert with hint or something like that, so `std::set` is a way to go

Comment: ...Or you could abuse `mutable` to be able to modify some parts of your objects.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a level of indirection via an adapter class. Something like below (examples adapting map, or individual map iterators, and showing don't have to change target function for vectors)...

```
// main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <type_traits>

// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56887842/c-map-with-custom-value-type
// From the original question
template <typename K, typename V>
struct Edge {
  K from;
  V to;

  int calculate_thing() { return 0; }
  void print_debug() { std::cout << "from='" << from << "', to='" << to << "'\n"; }
};

void do_stuff(int) {}
void do_more_stuff(int) {}

template<typename It>
void processEdges(It begin, It end) {
   for(auto it = begin; it != end; ++it) {
     do_stuff(it->from);
     do_more_stuff(it->calculate_thing());
     it->print_debug();
  }
}

// An additional level of indirection for maps
template <typename TMapIterator>
class MapValueIterator {
private:
  TMapIterator map_iterator;
  typedef typename std::iterator_traits<TMapIterator>::value_type map_iterator_type;

public:
  typedef ptrdiff_t difference_type;
  typedef typename map_iterator_type::second_type value_type;
  typedef value_type & reference;
  typedef value_type * pointer;
  typedef std::forward_iterator_tag iterator_category;

  MapValueIterator(TMapIterator map_iterator) : map_iterator(map_iterator) {}
  MapValueIterator(MapValueIterator &other) { map_iterator = other.map_iterator; }
  ~MapValueIterator() {}
  MapValueIterator& operator=(MapValueIterator &other) { map_iterator = other.map_iterator; return *this; }
  MapValueIterator operator++() { map_iterator++; return *this; }
  value_type*  operator*() const { return &map_iterator->second; }

  MapValueIterator operator++(int) {
    TMapIterator next_map_iterator(map_iterator);
    next_map_iterator++;
    return MapValueIterator(next_map_iterator);
  }

  value_type* operator->() const { return &map_iterator->second; }
  friend bool operator== (MapValueIterator const &left, MapValueIterator const &right) { return left.map_iterator == right.map_iterator; }
  friend bool operator!= (MapValueIterator const &left, MapValueIterator const &right) { return left.map_iterator != right.map_iterator; }
};

template <typename TMap>
class MapValueAdapter {
  TMap &map;
public:
  MapValueAdapter(TMap &map) : map(map) {}

  MapValueIterator<typename TMap::iterator> begin() { return MapValueIterator<typename TMap::iterator>(this->map.begin()); }
  MapValueIterator<typename TMap::iterator> end() { return MapValueIterator<typename TMap::iterator>(this->map.end()); }
};

// Map detection cribbed from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45042233/detect-if-type-is-a-mapping
template <typename T>
struct is_pair : std::false_type { };

template <typename T, typename U>
struct is_pair<std::pair<T, U>> : std::true_type { };

template <typename T>
constexpr bool is_pair_v = is_pair<T>::value;

template <typename TContainer>
typename std::enable_if<
  is_pair_v<typename std::iterator_traits<typename TContainer::iterator>::value_type>,
  MapValueAdapter<TContainer>
>::type
  adapt(TContainer &container) { return MapValueAdapter (container); }

template <typename TIterator>
typename std::enable_if<
  is_pair_v<typename std::iterator_traits<TIterator>::value_type>,
  MapValueIterator<TIterator>
>::type
  adapt(TIterator iterator) { return MapValueIterator (iterator); }

template <typename TContainer>
typename std::enable_if<
  !is_pair_v<typename std::iterator_traits<typename TContainer::iterator>::value_type>,
  TContainer &
>::type
  adapt(TContainer &container) { return container; }

int main(void)
{
  // Example where std::map, std::map::iterator and std::vector are adapted for processEdges() call.
  std::map<int, Edge<int, char>> map;
  map.insert_or_assign(2, Edge<int, char>{2, '2'});
  map.insert_or_assign(1, Edge<int, char>{1, '1'});
  std::vector<Edge<int, char>> const vector = { { 3, '3'}, {4, '4'} };
  auto map_adapter = adapt(map);
  auto vector_adapter = adapt(vector);

  std::cout << "Starting" << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Map\n";
  processEdges(map_adapter.begin(), map_adapter.end());
  std::cout << "Map Iterator\n";
  processEdges(adapt(map.begin()), adapt(map.end()));
  std::cout << "Vector\n";
  processEdges(vector_adapter.begin(), vector_adapter.end());
  std::cout << "Finished" << std::endl;
}
```

The output is:

> ```
> Starting
> Map
> from='1', to='1'
> from='2', to='2'
> Map Iterator
> from='1', to='1'
> from='2', to='2'
> Vector
> from='3', to='3'
> from='4', to='4'
> Finished
> ```

Answer (score -1):

you can use boost variant for this

```
 typedef boost::variant<std::string, std::map<std::string, std::string>> Value;
typedef std::map<std::string, Value> TheMapYouWouldUse;
```

Comment: the `value_type` of both of your maps is still `std::pair<const K,V>`, `std::pair<const std::string, std::string>` for the inner and `std::pair<const std::string, Value>` for the outer