# How to check if a variable is a map in C++?

Tags: c++, typeid

**EDIT**:
**This question is not a dupe. This is why...**

I do not want to test:
1) if a given type is a `map` (pseudocode: `type=="map"`), but 
2) if the type of a given variable is `map` (pseudocode: `typeof(var)=="map"`).

Having #1 (as in the linked question [Checking if a type is a map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35293470/checking-if-a-type-is-a-map)) is not enough. One has to chain it with a function that gets the `type` from the `var`.
I did not find that, so far (`typeid` does not seem to do the job).

---

**Now the original question**

I want to check if a given variable `var` is a `map` (regardless of the types of `first` and `second`), and without declaring any other variable.

**Is this possible? How?** 
Note: I don't care about getting the human-readable form "`map`", but only about getting a boolean for (pseudocode: `typeof(var)=="map"`).

**Is demangling (which is non-portable) the only way?**
[Unmangling the result of std::type_info::name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/281818/unmangling-the-result-of-stdtype-infoname)

---

**Posting an answer here**
(inspired by https://stackoverflow.com/a/35293682/2707864, which solves the issue for a type, not a variable).

```
template<typename T>
constexpr bool is_map(const T&) { return false; }

template<typename Key, typename Value, typename Order, typename Allocator>
constexpr bool is_map(const std::map<Key, Value, Order, Allocator>&) {
   return true;
}
```

Comment: Can you show what code you would use that utilizes this ability?

Comment: There's many [type traits](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types#Type_traits_.28since_C.2B.2B11.29) which could possibly be used.

Comment: And why do you need to do this? What is the actual problem that think such a check would solve? Please ask about that directly instead.

Comment: If you want a std::map specific template specialization SFINAE or partial specialization would be the way to do it.

Comment: @Galik - This would be embedded in a large code... I see no way of posting anything helpful as such. I could post a MCVE, but it wouldn't add anything. If you still think it may be useful, I could put this MCVE together.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude - There was another problem that led me to this question.
I was then interested in this specific question.
Asking about the other problem would be a different question, which I would post later on.
There is often a chain of problems that leads to solutions and learning on the road. I don't think one *should* always post the *original problem/question* instead of the *derived problem/question*. That should be up to the OP.
Of course, I would welcome comments on both, and that is why I would post both. Thanks!

Comment: @sancho.sReinstateMonica Note that an `std::map` class template takes more template parameters than just two. For example, an `std::map` with an allocator other than the default will result in `false` when calling your `is_map()`. By making them `constexpr` we can use it when a compile-time constant is needed.

Comment: @眠りネロク - Great... I put it together in a rush, and I knew I was leaving some cases out.
Now we have to wait for the question to be reopened.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a type trait like this:

```
template< typename T >
struct is_map : std::false_type {};

template< typename Key, typename Value, typename Order, typename Allocator >
struct is_map< std::map< Key, Value, Order, Allocator > > : std::true_type {};

struct Foo
{
    std::map< int, float > m_map;
    int m_int;
};

static_assert(is_map< decltype(Foo().m_map) >::value);
static_assert(!is_map< decltype(Foo().m_int) >::value);
```

Comment: The functions have a caveat that they may initiate type conversion from a different type and give a wrong answer.

Comment: Sorry again, those were not ordinary functions, but function *templates*. As far as I know, *implicit user-defined conversions* are **never** considered *during template argument deduction*. What am I missing? Thank you.

Comment: You're right, the `is_map(const T&)` overload would get picked. Still, I prefer to keep the type trait version as it doesn't involve template parameter deduction and overload resolution and directly operates on types.

Comment: Alright, thanks for clarifying, it has been a very constructive thinking exercise.

Comment: Usage example is given in the answer. `is_map< decltype(var) >::value`.

Comment: Perhaps your method can be adapted to a simpler usage (as in `is_map(var)`).
I have posted one such option at the end of the question.